# How to link to mysqlclient with Visualstudio for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a Linux project, which requires the use of pthreads and mysql. As IDE I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with the ['Visual C++ for Linux Developers' plugin](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/). This lets me code in Visual Studio and copies the source files to my linux machine before compiling and uses g++ there for compiling the code.

The problem is, that it links fine against pthread, but not against mysqlclient. I've added "-pthread -lmysqlclient" to the linker's command line option but still get unresolved reference errors regarding mysql_init and other mysql functions.
If I copy all compiler options to my linux machine and use them there from the command line, the code links just fine. Unfortunately I can't just let Visual Studio print me out the whole compiler call to look if everything is alright there.

Has someone experience with this and knows how to fix this?

Comment: It should be `-lpthread`, not `-pthread`. If it is actually `-pthread` maybe visual studio adds the `l` and you should try `-mysqlclient`. Do you get any error message such as `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient`?

Comment: Linking with -pthread from the commandline works as well for me as using -lpthread. -pthread is also listed in g++'s manpage. -mysqlclient in Visual Studio doesn't work. If I use it, I get the error "unrecognized command line option". I also used the -L parameter to point directly to the directory of libmysqlclient.so. Doesn't work either.